# Add a new column named CleanedText to a csv file in jupyter

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

I want to add a new column named CleanedText in a csv file in jupyter. The variable name for the file is e_data_raw.

Answer (score 0):

The code will be : 
e_data_raw.append(['CleanedText'])